# Realizar teste de Stress em C#

Tags: c#, testes, windows-service

Tenho o seguinte cenário: Existe um **Windows Service**, feito em C#, que é utilizado para sincronizar dados de uma base local com uma base na nuvem e preciso realizar alguns testes de *stress* e carga, com isso, pensei em realizar os seguintes teste:

1. Como esse serviço se comportaria com instabilidades na rede? Por exemplo, a internet caí no meio do processo e com isso fica impossibilitado por um tempo de executar a sincronização.
2. Simular uma lentidão no servidor que faça com que o processo demore mais para ser executado.
3. Simular uma grande carga de dados.

Gostaria de saber como posso simular esses casos de testes, principalmente o caso 1, já que isso é algo que o sistema precisa lidar, pois é um cenário já previsto que normalmente ocorre no ambiente o Windows Service está instalado.

Já li a respeito que normalmente, no caso de Windows Service, o ideal é exportar a *dll* dele para testar os métodos públicos dele nesse cenário, mas não sei até que ponto isso é verdade.

Comment: Pergunta indiretamente relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216574/57801

Answer (score 4):

O que eu acredito que possa auxiliar no quesito:

1. Não sei como a sua arquitetura foi modelada, mas a utilização de alguma biblioteca de Jobs possa resolver. Dá uma olhada na Hangfire, que tem schedule automático em exceptions. Desta forma se uma exception de network ou outra coisa for disparada, você não precisa se preocupar em reagendar a execução da chamada.
2. Infelizmente, não há uma forma simples de fazer isso. Acredito que você deva ter uma idéia do tipo de servidor que seu service vai rodar, então talvez uma máquina com Hyper-V onde você crie simulações de servidores com mais/menos recursos seja o caminho. Lentidão de processamento não só se dá pela execução, mas sim do processamento no servidor, memória disponível. Tem esta referência no MSDN que pode te dar um caminho: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2012/10/26/tools-to-simulate-cpu-memory-disk-load/
3. Se a sua arquitetura for totalmente desconectada, o correto seria separar a lógica do serviço própriamente dito, e realizar unit-tests ou load-tests nessa camada. Existem "n" bibliotecas para unit test, inclusive o Visual Studio tem uma ferramenta de load-tests.

Comment: Essa 1 meu sistema já faz isso, queria saber como eu poderia fazer um teste simulando o comportamento dele quando isso ocorrer.

Comment: Acredito que criar um unit-test, onde você aponte para um host inacessível, ou mesmo uma porta que não responda em um tempo acessivel e de timeout da conexão. Ou talvez um serviço no teste mesmo, em web API ou qualquer outra que faça um wait ou qualquer coisa simples, por um tempo que force a dar timeout. Mas esse é um cenário difícil de se testar com unit test, pois depende do ambiente. Tive uma situação, mas não em services, com Android, onde a gente mantinha uma conexão de wi-fi ligada, mas tiravamos o cabo de rede do servidor para simular timeout de conexão. Meio grotesco mas funcional.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, respondendo a lista:

1. O sistema tem que ser atômico, ou seja, deve ser transacionado para manter a integridade dos dados.
2. Para simular, basta alterar o hosts da máquina para um ip inválido e definir um timeout na transação(mencionado no item 1)
3. Não sei exatamente como está o sistema e sua arquitetura, dependendo do que seja essa carga de dados pode ser obtida utilizando o Jmeter como cliente.

Comment: O seu segundo item não me apeteceu. Por para um host inválido/inacessível não é simular lentidão, mas simular a perda do servidor (ele não é mais alcançável); seria mais parecido com o problema 1