# O que é um teste de stress?

Tags: testes, teste-stress

Estou vendo [algumas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=teste+de+stress) aqui no SO, antigas e novas, em diversas linguagens, que perguntam como fazer um teste de stress.

- O que seria um teste de stress?
- O que esse teste mede?
- Esse teste é uma maneira confiável de medir, seja lá o que tenha que ser medido?
- Em PHP, é aconselhável realizar alguns testes de stress? Se sim, onde eu poderia utilizá-lo?

Comment: Artigo que pode ser interessante: http://www.devmedia.com.br/testes-de-desempenho-carga-e-stress/26546

Comment: É ficar chutando o servidor até ele ficar brabo com você.

Comment: Assistir Domingão do Faustão

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Teste de stress** é realizado para submeter o software a situações extremas. Basicamente, o teste de stress baseia-se em testar os limites do software e avaliar seu comportamento. Assim, avalia-se até quando o software pode ser exigido e quais as falhas (se existirem) decorrentes do teste.

Os testes de stress são fundamentais em aplicações em que a eficiência seja uma característica importante. Por exemplo:

- Servidores de arquivos e servidores web, que devem atender a
  solicitações de um  grande número de clientes;
- Aplicações industriais, tais como o controle de  uma refinaria de
  petróleo;
- Jogos de computador, que precisam de um desempenho aceitável  para
  serem viáveis comercialmente.

Vamos considerar como exemplo a implementação de um servidor web utilizado em e-commerce. Ao estabelecer os requisitos do sistema, fixou-se um máximo de 5000 transações por minuto para uma determinada plataforma de execução. Um teste de stress pode, então, ser feito para responder a várias perguntas:

- O sistema consegue atingir o objetivo?
- Qual o número máximo de transações realmente possível?
- Se a plataforma de execução se degradar (por exemplo, uma falha
  parcial de rede, falta de espaço em disco, etc.), como o sistema se
  comportará?

Em certos casos é preferível que a execução do programa seja mantida mesmo que se degrade, evitando uma parada completa. Um exemplo típico são sistemas financeiros.

Possibilidades de falhas sob condições de operação difícil, como registrar operações incorretas, devem ser detectadas e evitadas. Um bom teste de stress deve poder revelar essas informações aos avaliadores.

A grande dificuldade de realizar um teste de stress é configurar adequadamente a plataforma de execução. Por exemplo: se o avaliador está interessado em saber a quantidade mínima de memória disponível para que um programa funcione, retirar fisicamente chips de RAM é uma solução muito trabalhosa. Além de RAM, há diversos outros parâmetros, como disco, CPU e instalações de rede, e seria inviável montar e desmontar um computador com diferentes configurações para todos os testes. Para isso, utilizam-se **ferramentas de stress**.

Um exemplo de ferramenta que pode ser utilizada para um teste de stress é o **WinStress**, da Ultra-X. Trata-se de um programa que permite reduzir artificialmente o desempenho de um computador, de acordo com a configuração desejada pelo avaliador. É possível variar parâmetros como carga de CPU, memória disponível, espaço em disco disponível e carga de rede.

Existem também ferramentas específicas para teste de aplicações em rede. Tais ferramentas permitem testar um programa simulando um número arbitrário de conexões. Alguns exemplos são **DieselTest** e **OpenSTA**, para aplicações Internet, e **DBMonster**, para teste de aplicações SQL.

**Outras ferramentas de stress:**

Existem uma tonelada de produtos open source para testes, olhe em http://www.opensourcetesting.org. Destes eu destaco os seguintes:

ab - http://httpd.apache.org ferramenta de stress do apache, útil para testes simples de carga.

jmeter - http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter funciona bem para gerar cargas pequenas/média de uma única máquina, testa protocolos diferentes de HTTP e permite criar cenários razoavelmente complexos.

tsung - [http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org) ferramenta capaz de simular cenários bem complexos usando modelagem estocástica de usuários. Funciona bem para gerar cargas enormes a partir de várias máquinas

slamd - http://www.slamd.com/ produto da sun muito legal, permite criação de cenários e funciona de maneira distribuida, consegue gerar cargas grandes, mas não se compara ao tsung.

siege - http://www.joedog.org/JoeDog/Siege muita gente que usa o siege para testes simples de carga, consegue gerar uma carga bem grande a partir de uma estação só, mas é um porre de processar os resultados ou usar cenários complexos.

---

**Hardware**

Para o teste de stress ser completamente eficiente, também é necessário saber se a máquina que esteja trabalhando possui uma boa capacidade, rede e afins, entre muitos N fatores que podem influenciar.

Mas deixo pelo menos uma ferramenta para teste:

[HeavyLoad](https://www.jam-software.com/heavyload/) permite fazer os seguintes testes:

- Stress CPU

Use seu processador ou mesmo um número específico de núcleos de processador para capacidade total. O HeavyLoad executa cálculos complexos para simular a carga no seu processador.

- Escrever arquivo de teste

Verifique como seu sistema se comporta quando confrontado com o menor espaço em disco

- Alocar memória

  Você gostaria de testar o quão bem seu computador funciona com memória escassa?

Entre muitos outros testes.

---

Você sabia:

**OS 13 PRINCIPAIS TIPOS DE TESTES DE SOFTWARE**

Quando falamos em testes de software devemos sempre lembrar que estes são divididos em diversos  tipos, de acordo com seu objetivo particular.

**1. Teste de Configuração**

Testa se o software funciona no hardware a ser instalado.

**2. Teste de Instalação**

Testa se o software instala como planejado, em diferentes hardwares e sob diferentes condições, como pouco espaço  de memória, interrupções de rede, interrupções na instalação etc.

**3. Teste de Integridade**

Testa a resistência do software à falhas (robustez).

**4. Teste de Segurança**

Testa se o sistema e os dados são acessados de maneira segura, apenas pelo autor das ações.

**5. Teste Funcional**

Testa os requisitos funcionais, as funções e os casos de uso. “A aplicação faz o que deveria fazer?”

**6. Teste de Unidade**

Testa um componente isolado ou classe do sistema.

**7. Teste de Integração**

Testa se um ou mais componentes combinados funcionam de maneira satisfatória. Há quem diga que o teste de integração é composto por vários testes de unidade.

**8. Teste de Volume**

Testa o comportamento do sistema operando com o volume “normal”  de dados  e transações envolvendo o banco de dados durante um longo período de tempo.

**9. Teste de Performance**

O teste de performance se divide em 3 tipos:

- Teste de carga
- Testa o software sob as condições normais de uso. Ex.: tempo de resposta, número de transações por minuto, usuários simultâneos etc.
- Teste de stress (como explicado acima)
- Teste de estabilidade: Testa se o sistema se mantém funcionando de maneira satisfatória após um período de uso.

**10. Teste de Usabilidade**

Teste focado na experiência do usuário, consistência da interface, layout, acesso às funcionalidades etc.

**11. Testes de Caixa Branca e Caixa Preta**

Basicamente, teste de caixa branca envolve o código e o de caixa-preta, não.

**12. Teste de Regressão**

Reteste de um sistema ou componente para verificar se alguma modificação recente causou algum efeito indesejado, além de, certificar se o sistema ainda atende os requisitos.

**13. Teste de Manutenção**

Testa se a mudança de ambiente não interferiu no funcionamento do sistema.

---

- Tópicos Relacionados:

[Qual é a diferença entre um teste de carga e um teste de stress?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248671/57801)

Comment: Eu acho que dada a expectativa de que nós escrevamos soluções cada vez mais escaláveis, o que se testa é a capacidade de resistir a situações extremas da combinação hardware + software, e não apenas do software. I.e.: com memória, armazenamento e banda infinitas, processadores mágicos e latência zero, nenhum software jamais teria qualquer problema de stress de qualquer natureza.

Comment: @Renan algoritmo ruim mina até uma Máquina de Turing perfeita

Comment: Adicionei um pequeno trecho para essa parte. Pois isso possui N fatores que precisaria ser levantado.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado uma Máquina de Turing é uma abstração que possui memória e tempo infinitos à sua disposição. Um computador real não é uma Máquina de Turing =p

Comment: @Renan por isso que disse que até para algo perfeito e ideal pode ser minado por um algoritmo ruim

Comment: Não. Para uma máquina de Turing, o conceito de um algoritmo ser melhor ou pior do que outro não faz sentido. Ela lida igualmente com um algoritmo mais ou menos complexo. Tratar análise de performance ou de complexidade com máquinas de Turing não faz sentido.