# Teste unitário é um termo genérico? Quais tipos existem? E quais formas de aplicar?

Tags: terminologia, testes, testes-de-unidade

**Teste unitário é um termo genérico** para qualquer teste de uma parte independente de um programa? Ou é um **termo exclusivo para paradigmas orientado a objeto**, com procedimentos já conhecidos?

Sempre que encontro qualquer *post* relacionado a teste unitário, a grande maioria cita terminologia já pertencente ao assunto (mock, testes automatizados, etc). Forma uma grade de disciplina oras dando a impressão de ser um termo genérico, oras dando a impressão de ser uma boa prática universal a plataforma de desenvolvimento. Outros *posts* bem intencionados em relação a pergunta, focam a aplicação do teste unitário a determinada plataforma (Shell, jasmine, etc). Outros ainda começam com uma boa definição, mas acabam desviando para exemplos práticos, se afastando da definição que ainda não compreendi. O resultado destas leituras geralmente é ter mais dúvidas do que respostas.

**Quais os principais tipos que existem? E quais formas de aplicar destes?**

Existem dois bons tópicos aqui no SOpt, mas que não saciaram minhas dúvidas completamente (além de serem perguntas diferentes):
[Qual a diferença entre teste unitário e teste integrado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115146/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-teste-unit%C3%A1rio-e-teste-integrado)
[Para que servem Testes Unitários e quais as vantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53678/para-que-servem-testes-unit%C3%A1rios-e-quais-as-vantagens)

Comment: Relacionada: [O que é um teste de stress?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216571/66203)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maior parte do que quer saber já foi respondido em [Testes, TDD, Unit Test, QA e assemelhados. Qual a diferença dos conceitos sobre testes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/101).

Teste de unidade ([teste unitário é o termo errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/567879/101)) tem a ver com qualidade do código, serve para melhorar a robustez dele, e pode ser aplicado para qualquer paradigma.

A orientação a objeto pode ajudar um pouco aplicar testes de unidade, mas a [programação modular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101) também. Tem mais a ver com a forma de desenvolver do que com o paradigma específico.

Não existes vários tipos de testes de unidade, existem várias técnicas de aplicá-lo, existem diversas ferramentas.

O que é genérico e o que é específico depende do ponto de vista, toda terminologia pode ser genérica ou específica de acordo como é usada. Então o termo é genérico em certo sentido e é específico em outro.

Leia o [artigo da Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teste_de_unidade) ([em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)) para entender melhor, ali tem os conceitos. O meu entendimento é que as pessoas dificultam o que é fácil, muitas vezes com abordagem "práticas" que não ensinam o que importa e que fará a pessoa saber como, e principalmente, porque usar.

A pergunta é genérica, para obter respostas específicas, precisa de perguntas específicas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).