# O que é um teste automatizado?

Tags: testes

Olhando por cima, o termo em questão parece-me essencial na rotina de desenvolvimento, então de forma simples, o que é um teste automatizado e quais as vantagens? se possível um exemplo prático de como faze-los.

Comment: [Para que servem Testes Unitários e quais as vantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53678/91) e [Testes, TDD, Unit Test, QA e assemelhados. Qual a diferença dos conceitos sobre testes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/19177/91)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Para que servem Testes Unitários e quais as vantagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53678/para-que-servem-testes-unit%c3%a1rios-e-quais-as-vantagens)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Teste Automatizado é o uso de um software para controlar a execução do teste de software, comparando os resultados esperados com os resultados reais.
Onde eu trabalho utilizamos o TestComplete para a automatização dos testes em aplicações Desktop, mas existem inúmeros outros disponíveis, tanto para aplicações desktop quanto para web. Exemplos: Microsoft Test Manager, SoapUI, Selenium Web Driver, etc.

A automação de testes traz diversas vantagens: é mais rápido, diminui a chance de erro humano (mas é preciso atentar para que os scripts não apresentem falhas) e reduz o esforço com tarefas repetitivas, liberando os testadores para atividades que exijam raciocínio humano.

Exemplos de testes que podem ser feitos com ferramentas de automação:

1. Relacionar o item
2. Desempenho
3. Estresse
4. Segurança
5. Monitoramento de utilização de recursos
6. Gerenciamento de dados

Recomendo a leitura dos seguintes links:

1. [Introdução a automação de testes](http://www.qualister.com.br/blog/introducao-a-automacao-de-testes)
2. [Teste automatizado, por onde eu começo?](http://www.knowledge21.com.br/blog/testes-automatizados-por-onde-eu-comeco/)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/216574/57801